# What is the logic for defining related questions?

Tags: support

There are a section with related questions in the right hand side bar. What is the logic/algorithm for defining related questions?

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected

Comment: @rene: Makes it sense to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I would be merely copying that answer and have nothing to add at this moment so me writing an answer is not very likely. Feel free to self-answer.